# trying to install ubuntu 14.10 from usb on a pc with 9.04

Tags: boot

My computer right now has Ubuntu 9.04, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.10 using a bootable USB stick. If not mistaken, I did that process right, but the thing is when I boot the pen drive, a message shows up a little after:

```
SysLinux 3.64 Debian-2008-07-15 Ebios Copyright (c) 1994-2008 M. peter Anvin.  
Missing parameter in configuration file.  
Unknown Keyword in Configuration file.  
Boot:
```

Now, 'Im using an old HP computer with the Windows Vista Basic sticker on it, not sure how old it is and what model, and I don't know if I'm making a mistake somewhere, does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the following things:

1. .iso Image of Ubuntu 14.10 is 32/64bit matching to your microprocessor's architecture i.e. 32 bit microprocessor can locate boot image of 32bit OS
2. Your PC must meet minimum requirements for your desired OS to get installed.
3. Check for list of files in a bootable device (Your USB device) to ensure that it is successfully made bootable.

Comment: my pc has 2,0 gb ram, and i downloaded ubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386 the x32 i think i did that right, im not sure how to check for list of files O.o